# Form is submitting even if javascript function return false

Tags: javascript, html

Javascript validation is not working! Form is submitting even if function returns false. Where i should make changes? Here is the part of the code i wrote.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function check()
    {
        temp=document.getElementById("name").value;
        if(temp=="")
        {
            document.getElementById("err").innerHTML="error found";
            document.getElementById("name").focus();
            return false;
        }            
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>        
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="name">
        <div id="err"></div>
        <input type="submit" onClick="check()">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try `onClick="return check()"`

Comment: there are other ways to submit a form. don't attach to a button. use `onSubmit`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `onSubmit` event of `form` instead of `onClick` event of `button`.

You also need to use `return` with HTML `onevent` attributes

*HTML*

```
<form onSubmit="return check()">
    <input type="text" id="name"/>
    <div id="err"></div>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cD2cJ/)